# Why doesn't my Lightroom smart photoset have any pictures in it?

Tags: software, lightroom, smart-collections

I've created a "Smart Photoset" in Lightroom to publish photos to Flickr, configured to match **all** of the following rules:

1. Collection contains "Nepal"
2. Pick Flag is flagged

I assumed, possibly naively, that this meant that when I flagged any pictures (by clicking the little flag icon in the Library grid) in my "Nepal 2010" and "Nepal 2011" Collections, that they would automatically appear in my shiny new Smart Photoset. They do not. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I may have discovered the solution to this myself, but for the benefit of others who stumble across this question later, [this adobe forum post clears up the situation](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4158099).

In summary: in Lightroom 3, the flagged status of a photograph is not global. Only photographs flagged in folders or other smart collections will show up in a smart collection configured to include flagged photographs. Apparently, this "feature" is no longer a problem in Lightroom 4.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is why you saw the problem you did. At least, it's what I was going to suggest.